# How to wrap a C++ factory method in a Python __init__ function using SWIG

Tags: c++, python, swig

I'm porting a Python extension module written in C++ from Boost.Python to SWIG.

The C++ code defines an abstract class `X` with a static factory method

```
class X {
public:
    static X* create(const char* descr);
    ...
};
```

The factory method returns a pointer to an instance of some derived class.

With Boost.Python you can wrap the C++ class `X` in a Python class `X` that has an

```
__init__(self, descr)
```

method that calls `X::create`. In fact, it is done as follows:

```
namespace bp = boost::python;

bp::class_<X>("X", boost::no_init)
    .def("__init__", bp::make_constructor(&X::create))
    ...
```

Is there a way of doing the same thing with SWIG?

Comment: Is there a reason the C++ code doesn't use a constructor? Is there a reason reflecting the factory function as a factory function is unacceptable?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use the factor function as `__new__` rather than `__init__`?

Comment: @user763305: `__new__` is the right place, as it controls object creation. `__init__` controls instance state initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, it is better to use `__new__` for controlling how a class is created. In SWIG, you should create an interface (.i) file that looks as follows:

```
%extend X {
  static X * __new__(const char *desc) { return create(desc); }
};
```